# How can I create custom hooks for my mocha tests?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, hook

I am maintaining unit tests for an HTTP server written with Express, and I have a LOT of duplicated code in my beforeEach hooks.

In order to factorize that code, I want to create two custom hooks `prepare()` and `execute()` that would act as "ordered beforeEach hooks".

Here is how they would be used:

```js
describe('Root', () => {
    prepare(() => {
        console.log('Root/Prepare');
    });

    execute(() => {
        console.log('Root/Execute');
    });

    it('Root test', () => {
        expect(true).to.be.true;
    });

    describe('Sub', () => {
        prepare(() => {
            console.log('Sub/Prepare');
        });

        execute(() => {
            console.log('Sub/Execute');
        });

        it('Sub test', () => {
            expect(true).to.be.true;
        });
    });
});
```

The expected output for "Root test" would be:

```
Root/Prepare
Root/Execute
```

And for "Sub test", it would be:

```
Root/Prepare
Sub/Prepare
Root/Execute
Sub/Execute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocha exposes an API to create custom hooks. You can get it [here](https://mochajs.org/api/hook).